# Multiple concurrent browser tests with watir-webdriver through different browsers

Tags: ruby, concurrency, watir, watir-webdriver

so I'm working on a website here and I would like to run multiple browser tests at one time. What I mean by this is it should perform my smoke tests on ie, firefox and chrome at the same time and report back each browser results. I'm currently only testing with ie with rpsec and watir-webdriver but would like to automate for the other 2 browsers. Are there any existing gems out there (I haven't been able to find any), if not what would be the best way to go around solving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try **[WatirGrid](https://github.com/90kts/watirgrid)**.

It won't make all the work for you but it will give you a platform to launch multiple tests at once. The you can just launch the same test 3 times changing the target browser and the grid will handle where they will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't need anything except watir-webdriver to run multiple browsers on the same machine.

```
ie = Watir::Browser.new :ie
firefox = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
chrome = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
opera = Watir::Browser.new :opera
```

Comment: Well, "at the same time" is impossible anyway. What does "at the same time" mean anyway? At the same second? Millisecond? You can open all browsers, do something in one browser, do the same thing in another browser... When you are done with all browsers, do something else in the fist browser, the second browser... Rinse, repeat.

Comment: LOL  that's a common reframe for me when people give too loose of loadtesting criteria..  especially given most networks send data serially, to have a setup where a server can actually get multiple requests 'at the same time' is pretty difficult when you start slicing the time really finely.   But in this case I think perhaps he means having the scripts running in parallel, perhaps on multiple systems or VM's  to reduce time between when a build is ready, and test results can be known.

Comment: Not sure if thats the correct place for this comment-question, please excuse me if i'm wrong, but, its "fine" to launch the same features test on both Firefox and Chrome at the same time in the same machine? My tests work fine sequentially but the FF execution fails if Chrome is executing at the same time...

Comment: You should be able to execute tests using different browsers at the same time at one machine.

Comment: Thanks Zeljko. I found my problem: when launching two executions at the same time, when one of the browsers (i.e. Firefox) end the tests, i use the hook:

 at_exit do
  browser.close
  if @use_headless
   headless.destroy
  end
end

...and this also closes the other browser (i.e. Chome), giving a Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED) error. I'm looking for a better way to close the browser :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple machines or VMs to work with, [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) in the answer.  My approach is similar to Chuck's, but instead of a flat configuration file I let Jenkins prompt for these values via drop-down menu, etc.  Jenkins is easy to set up and can automatically distribute test jobs to any available machine for testing.

So, I click "Google Search Test" and select "Internet Explorer"... then I do the same thing and select a different browser.   Concurrent tests in various browsers, with HTML/email output and a great log history.

I'll also be writing more about this, but I'm still on vacation!

Here is an example of configuration file (these assign default values if for example Jenkins is not used to launch them).  NOTE: "||=" means "if nil, use this value. If not nil, use the current value". I'm only setting values if Jenkins has not already.

```
ENV['BROWSER'] ||= "firefox"

ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] ||= "qa"

ENV['LIMIT'] ||= "10"

ENV['DISTRICT'] ||= "any"

ENV['TYPE'] ||= "pkg-new"

# Not necessary, but added for sanity/cleanliness:
$type = ENV['TYPE'].downcase
$browser = ENV['BROWSER'].downcase
$env = ENV['ENVIRONMENT'].downcase
$district = ENV['DISTRICT'].downcase

puts "\t** Testing #{$env.upcase} using #{$browser.upcase}... **"
```

The Jenkins portion is surprisingly easy - so easy I didn't think it was set up.  You create a Variable for your script, and whatever you name the variable becomes ENV["VariableName"] - and is immediately available to your script.

So I have a variable named "BROWSER" that is set by a drop down with Firefox, IE and Chrome options.  The user has no room to confuse the script with free text, and they can run a custom test whenever they want.  My Devs/PMs/Users love me :D.

Comment: how do you take care of having Jenkins tell the scripts which browser type to use?  is it a command line parameter?  or do you have multiple versions of your scripts for different browsers and it runs the appropriate one?

Comment: When the user chooses an option via menu or writes in text, Jenkins automatically stores it to an environment variable that it magically makes available to scripts.  So, I have a flat file like yours that assigns a default value to the variable if it is nil (in case we're running locally and not via Jenkins).  I'll add the snip to my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, the magic of environment variables.  That's another great way to externalize those values from the scripts, I may end up switching to that down the road.  I could for example even update the readconfig method to check for an ENV variable and use that if found, otherwise get the value from the config file. Then you could basically have your choice of which way to control things, with one 'trumping' another.  and THANKS for taking time during your vacation to share that with us.

Comment: It's difficult to properly use Cucumber and set up iterative tests (allowing the user to enter the number of iterations which then gets passed to the test).  For that reason I've improperly used Cucumber features a few ways, but when my Java Dev wants to run 10 tests for a new build, or 1,000 tests for a more mature build with any number of other options he has requested that I add, he can.  No waiting for my free time, and we all get notified by email.  It's definitely worklife-changing.

Comment: are you going to the watir test automation conf in Austin in March? I'd love to pick your brain re lessons learned using Jenkins.  We're just moving to that for CI for a new greenfield project and I need to get myself sorted to have it run my cucumber tests, do some REST based API testing, etc.

Comment: I was based in Austin until about a year ago, I didn't have plans to attend as yet, but I'll look into it.  I'd be happy to share whatever information I can.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the exact same test code for the tests you will need to externalize the browser type, either as an environment variable, or a YAML file or somesuch.

Ruby has some stuff that makes dealing with yaml files super easy (I need to write a blog posting on this) so you can put something at the top of your script that calls a method to get the config info and then set the browser type accordingly.

In my `testconfig.yml` YAML file I have:

```
global:
    browser: ie               #possible values: ie, ff, chrome
```

note I don't currently test against opera (market segment too small) or it would be in the list of possible values.  The comment is just there to make life easy on whoever might have to edit that file.

I have a `read_config` method defined in a `readconfig.rb` file which looks (in part) like this

```
require 'yaml'

def read_config
  config = YAML.load_file('testconfig.yml')
  $browser_type = config['global']['browser']
end
```

And at the top of my tests there is code like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'readconfig'
require 'watir-webdriver'
read_config

$browser = Watir::Browser.new $browser_type.to_sym
```

This way I can have a different config file on each system (which also sets up a lot of other things like the current passwords (changed on a regular basis), which test environment to use, and settings for each environment for stuff like the test server URL's, database server and name, etc.   When developing tests a simple change to the config file lets me run all the tests facing a given browser.  or if I want to run in parallel I can have the systems setup with their own customized config file, let them pull the current scripts from source control, and then run them against whatever browser, server etc is configured in the config file.

This is probably dirt simple stuff to any accomplished ruby dev, but it's like magic for any of us new to ruby, and especially for getting hard-coded values OUT of my scripts and into one single place where I can control and change them.

Comment: This seem like a good idea, I shall be waiting for your blog post.

Comment: It may be a while.   In the meantime if any of these answers helped you greatly you might want to accept it.  otherwise let us know what more we could do to give you a better answer.