# syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end }

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am new to Ruby, I don't quite get what is happening here,

This code works

```
chrome = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
firefox = Watir::Browser.new:firefox
ie = Watir::Browser.new:ie

browser_conf = {
    "chrome" => chrome,
    "firefox" => firefox,
    "ie" => ie
}
```

But the following code produces a syntax error:

```
browser_conf = {
    "chrome" => Watir::Browser.new:chrome,
    "firefox" => Watir::Browser.new:firefox,
    "ie" => Watir::Browser.new:ie
}
```

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
>       }

Why is it so? Is there a way I can write implicitly without assigning them to a separate variable?

Comment: Some have voted to close this question.! If anyone can explain how this can be improved it will be very helpful

Comment: Looking at the edit (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45481010/revisions), it looks like the main issue was that the title did not inform us of what the issue was. Although I've found some SO users will try to close questions if the code examples in them are wrong, which is utterly bizarre to me, when the aim is to find and correct the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some slightly unsual syntax in play here, with a single colon (:) at the end of the `new` call. E.g.

```
chrome = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
```

This is probably confusing the hash parser, which can use colons as a key/value separater, since ruby 1.9. E.g.

```
hash = {foo: 'bar'}
```

You can always force a piece of code to be evaluated regardless of it's surroundings, however, by wrapping it in brackets. You'll probably find this code works:

```
browser_conf = {
  "chrome" => (Watir::Browser.new:chrome),
  "firefox" => (Watir::Browser.new:firefox),
  "ie" => (Watir::Browser.new:ie)
}
```

*Update:* I've just checked the Watir docs, and I believe you're calling `new` incorrecly. The symbol for the browser is an argument to `new`. So should either be after a space, or in brackets. Without either white space or brackets, it's not always able to parse that as an argument.

Here's the correct code:

```
browser_conf = {
  "chrome" => Watir::Browser.new(:chrome),
  "firefox" => Watir::Browser.new(:firefox),
  "ie" => Watir::Browser.new(:ie)
}
```

Comment: _"should either be after a space [...]"_ – `{ 'chrome' => Watir::Browser.new :chrome }` doesn't work, parentheses are mandatory here.

Answer (score 4):

I think here is the issue

```
chrome = Watir::Browser.new:chrome
firefox = Watir::Browser.new:firefox
ie = Watir::Browser.new:ie
```

Change that to (paranthesis for argument)

```
chrome = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)
firefox = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
ie = Watir::Browser.new(:ie)
```

or to (space before argument)

```
chrome = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
firefox = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
ie = Watir::Browser.new :ie
```

Comment: `chrome = Watir::Browser.new:chrome` (without a space) is unusual, but does indeed work. You just cannot omit the parentheses in a hash literal.

Answer (score 3):

Passing methods arguments without parentheses can easily become ambiguous. Take this hash literal for example:

```
{ 1 => foo 2, 3 => 4 }
```

That could be interpreted either as:

```
{ 1 => foo(2, 3 => 4) }
```

or as:

```
{
  1 => foo(2),
  3 => 4
}
```

Same for this array literal:

```
[foo 2, 3, 4]
```

That could be:

```
[foo(2, 3, 4)]
[foo(2, 3), 4]
[foo(2), 3, 4]
```

When Ruby's parser encounters such ambiguity, it usually raises a `SyntaxError`. You then have to explicitly provide parentheses.

In your case:

```
{ 'chrome' => Watir::Browser.new(:chrome) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an space before the argument of browser name.
Give paranthesis or a space.
Alternatively for doing it dynamically..
any of these posts will help you on stackoverflow -

> If you want to call different environment through command line go to -
>   [link-one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371181/run-tests-in-multiple-browsers-with-ruby-watir-webdriver-cucumber-and-parall)
>
> For Ruby symbols to be passed take reference from - [link-two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669113/multiple-concurrent-browser-tests-with-watir-webdriver-through-different-browser)

Otherwise,

> Comparison between doing it with Watir vs Webdriver, please visit -
>   [External Link](http://3qilabs.com/testing-in-multiple-browser-windows-with-watir-and-watir-webdriver/)

You need to make changes to env.sh and ensure you pass 'browser-type' or equivalent variable which you can refer in config file and instantiate respective one.
Hope it helps!